# Difference between BinaryWriter and BinaryFormatter.Serialize?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter, binarywriter

I'm new to object serialization, and in the course of my learning how to read from and write to a file (deserialize and serialize) using `BinaryFormatter`, I came across `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`, which seemed to be doing the same thing.

Is there some subtle difference between `BinaryFormatter.Serialize()` and `BinaryWriter`? Or is `BinaryWriter` just a more compact way performing the the same action as `BinaryFormatter.Serialize()`?

Comment: Potential codeproject article that might be of some use to you [BinaryFormatter vs. Manual Serializing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311944/BinaryFormatter-or-Manual-serializing)

Comment: Just to update anyone that may come across this, BinaryFormatter is now considered "dangerous" to use if user input is involved. For more details:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`BinaryWriter` is used to write primitive types in binary to a stream and supports writing strings in a specific encoding. `BinaryFromatter` is responsible for serializing an entire object or graph of connected objects into binary format. So, I suppose you can say `BinaryWriter` is a much more elementary form of something like `BinaryFormatter`.

I got this information here: [BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) & [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

`BinaryWriter` and `BinaryFormatter` are two different thing.

`BinaryFormatter` is used for serialization. It helps you to map a C# object to a binary representation which you can write to a file, a network stream etc.

But `BinaryWriter` does not help you map the C# object to binary data. It just gives you the ability to write binary data (as the name implies). So you give it primitive types like an int, it converts it into binary and write it. After writing when you need reading it you have to use a `BinaryReader` and you must know somehow that you have to read an int. So you have to serialize your data somehow yourself.

You can say `BinaryFormatter` uses `BinaryWriter` to be able to write binary data but it does a lot of other jobs to automatically serialize and deserialize your object.

Comment: "BinaryWriter does not help you map the C# object to binary data" --- That's actually exactly how it helps. 

Corey Berigan's answer is spot on. Both BinaryWriter and BinaryFormatter are used to serialize objects as bytes and write those bytes to a stream. The difference is that BinaryWriter is intended to serialize primitives in a way that can be later read by BinaryReader. BinaryFormatter is intended for serializing more complex object graphs, where instances are marked [Serializable].

"BinaryFormatter uses BinaryWriter to be able to write binary data" -- Are you sure? I'd be surprised.

Comment: @RonnieOverby , I think u misunderstood me, By C# Object I meant a complex object not a primitive as I have mentioned that you can write primitive objects to binary using BinaryWriter. BinaryFormatter do use BinaryWriter. It's simple and obvious actually cause finally it should break down complex object to primitives and then write them. You can see the implementation although to become sure: 
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters/src/System/Runtime/Serialization/Formatters/Binary/BinaryFormatterWriter.cs